# This is the error I'm getting: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to double[]

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class randomArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] awesome = gimm();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(awesome));


}
public static int[] gimme() {
    int[] array = new int[40];
    for(int i = 1; i< array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random()*40);
    }
    return array;
}
public static double[] gimm() {
    double mean = 0.0, variance = 0.0, sum = 0.0;
    int ayeArray[] = gimme();

    for(int i= 1; i<ayeArray.length;i++) 
        sum += ayeArray[i];
    mean = sum/ayeArray.length;

    for(int i= 1; i<ayeArray.length;i++) 
        variance = Math.pow(ayeArray[i] - mean, 2);
    variance = variance/ayeArray.length;

        return variance;

        }
}
```

Comment: true, variance is not an array!

Comment: You are returning variance which is a double, but your method is expecting an array of doubles to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The variable variable is a double. You are returning variance, so you are returning a double. However the method is defined to be a double[]. You have to return a double[].

There is your problem, let me know if you require further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variance variable as double and return it, but your method gimm() returns the array double[].

Answer (score 0):

The `variance` in `gimm()` method is double, but the return type of your method is `double[]` which is array of doubles.
Change return type of your method to double like this.

`public static double gimm() { ...}`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have declared the gimm() function to return a double[]. When in reality you end up returning at the end of the function a normal double value. I suggest you make variance into a double array (as in double[]). Everything else seems to be set.